# Cordial saludo, soy nueva en C# ,no se porque no me aparece nada en la consola

Tags: c#

Cuando intento ejecutar mi codigo ,aparece 0 errores,pero aun asi no me imprime nada en la consola: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es mi código:

```
static String recibirCa(String texto){
  String contenido = "textos";
  recibirCa(contenido);
  Console.WriteLine("contenido");
  return contenido; 
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar todo el código? Si puedes pegarlo en la pregunta en lugar de colocar una captura sería mucho mejor. Y si puedes explicar qué es lo que intentas lograr al crear la función recibirCa y luego volver a llamarla de manera recursiva, sería genial. Un saludo.

Comment: de esta manera era que tenia el codigo cuando subi la captura , 
static String recibirCa(String texto)
{

    String contenido = "textos";
    recibirCa(contenido);
    Console.WriteLine("el mensaje es " + contenido);

    Console.ReadKey();
  return contenido;


} lo que quiero hacer con el metodo recibirCa  es que al pasarle una cadena  de texto como parametro y que  me devuelva esa cadena texto

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que estás llamando el método `recibirCa(String texto)` recursivamente, posiblemente tengas un error del tipo `StackOverflowException` que impide la impresión del texto, debes eliminar su llamado dentro del mismo método.

```
static String recibirCa(String texto){
  String contenido = texto;
  //recibirCa(contenido);
  Console.WriteLine(contenido);
  return contenido; 
}
```

Recuerda que para escribir en la ventana de salida (`Output`), también puedes usar `Debug.WriteLine()`:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Hola Dahiana!");
```

Comment: gracias , pero aun no me sirve :(,me sale esto en la consola:pruebaTecnica.exe (proceso 1328) se cerró con el código 0.
Presione cualquier tecla para cerrar esta ventana. . .

Answer (score 0):

Veo que estas en net6.0 donde [La plantilla de aplicación de consola de C# de .NET 6 genera instrucciones de nivel superior.](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-mx/dotnet/core/tutorials/top-level-templates) Ten en cuenta eso.

Creo que lo que intentas hacer es algo como esto:

```
recibirCa("algun texto");

static void recibirCa(String texto)
{

    Console.WriteLine(texto);
    
}
```

Aunque si lo que quieres es que tu función devuelva una cadena sería así:

```
Console.WriteLine(recibirCa("algún texto"));

static string recibirCa(String texto)
{
    return texto;
}
```

Pero eso no tendría mucho sentido ya que nos estaría devolviendo el mismo dato que le pasamos como argumento. Normalmente dentro de la función realizamos algún procedimiento con los argumentos que nos pasan. Un simple ejemplo sería añadir un poco mas de texto así:

```
Console.WriteLine(recibirCa("algún texto"));

static string recibirCa(String texto)
{

    return texto + "texto adicional";
}
```